# Python regex pattern building

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to incrementally build the following regex pattern in python using reusable pattern components. I'd expect the pattern *p* to match the text in *lines* completely but it ends up matching only the first line..

```
import re
nbr = re.compile(r'\d+')
string = re.compile(r'(\w+[ \t]+)*(\w+)')
p1 = re.compile(rf"{string.pattern}\s+{nbr.pattern}\s+{string.pattern}")
p2 = re.compile(rf"{nbr.pattern}\s+{string.pattern}")
p1orp2 = re.compile(rf"{p1.pattern}|{p2.pattern}")
p = re.compile(rf"({p1orp2.pattern}\n)+")

lines = (f"aaaa 100284 aaaa\n"
         f"aaaa 365870 bbbb\n"
         f"757166 cccc\n"
         f"111054 cccc\n"
         f"999657 dddd\n"
         f"999 eeee\n"
         f"2955 ffff\n")

match = p.search(lines)
print(match)
print(match.group(0))
```

here's what gets printed:
<re.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='aaaa 1284 aaaa'>
aaaa 1284 aaaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
p1orp2 = re.compile(rf"{p1.pattern}|{p2.pattern}")
p = re.compile(rf"({p1orp2.pattern}\n)+")
```

In `p` the `\n` is appended to `p1orp2`, but this influences the scope of the `|` in `p1orp2`: the added `\n` belongs to the second option, not to the first option. It is the same if you would have attached that `\n` already in the definition of `p1orp2`:

```
p1orp2 = re.compile(rf"{p1.pattern}|{p2.pattern}\n")
p = re.compile(rf"({p1orp2.pattern})+")
```

...while you really want to allow the `p1` pattern to be followed by `\n` as well:

```
p1orp2 = re.compile(rf"{p1.pattern}\n|{p2.pattern}\n")
p = re.compile(rf"({p1orp2.pattern})+")
```

To achieve that with the `\n` where it was, you could use parentheses in the definition of `p1orp2` so it limits the scope of the `|` operator:

```
p1orp2 = re.compile(rf"({p1.pattern}|{p2.pattern})")
p = re.compile(rf"({p1orp2.pattern}\n)+")
```

With this change it will work as you intended.

Comment: thank you! that was exactly the problem preventing the pattern from working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the regex pattern is that the capturing group in p1 only captures the last word in the sequence of words separated by whitespace or tabs. Therefore, the second part of p1 matches only the last word in the second line, and the first part of p1 and p2 don't match the lines that don't start with a word. As a result, p1orp2 doesn't match the entire input.

To fix this, you need to modify string to capture all the words in the sequence, not just the last one. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
     word_sequence = re.compile(r"\w+(?:[ \t]+\w+)*")
            nbr = re.compile(r"\d+")
            p1 = re.compile(rf"{word_sequence.pattern}\s+{nbr.pattern}\s+ 
           {word_sequence.pattern}")
           p2 = re.compile(rf"{nbr.pattern}\s+{word_sequence.pattern}")
           p1orp2 = re.compile(rf"{p1.pattern}|{p2.pattern}")
           p = re.compile(rf"({p1orp2.pattern}\n)+")
    
           lines = (
              f"aaaa 1284 aaaa\n"
              f"aaaa 3650 bbbb\n"
              f"75071 cccc\n"
              f"111872214054 cccc\n"
              f"999 dddd\n"
              f"999 eeee\n"
              f"295255 ffff\n"
                 )
    
         match = p.search(lines)
         print(match)
         print(match.group(0))
```

Comment: I tried the change you suggested but still end up only matching the first line. I've even tried simplifying word sequence to just a single word as in `word = re.compile(r"\w+")`, but it still only matches the first line

Comment: The problem is that p.search() only finds the first match in the string, and in your case, the first match is the first line in lines. To find all the matches, you can use p.finditer() instead of p.search(). p.finditer() returns an iterator that generates MatchObject instances, each of which represents a separate match. try this code: matches = p.finditer(lines)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(0))